# Printing a given number sequence in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to print number sequence like following in mysql:
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
.
.
to 16 times

I am trying this:

```
select (t*16+1) x from
(select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 ) A
,
(select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 )B
order by x;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
    SELECT 1 num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1 FROM cte WHERE num < 16
)
SELECT t1.num
FROM cte t1
CROSS JOIN cte t2
WHERE t1.num <= 3
ORDER BY t2.num, t1.num;
```

---

> For versions without window functions such as 5.7 I wonder if we can do it using a single statement ? – blabla_bingo

```sql
SELECT t0.id
FROM ( SELECT 1 id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 ) t0
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 ) t1
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 ) t2
ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id, t0.id
```

Comment: That's a good answer for 8.0.  For versions without window functions such as 5.7 I wonder if we can do it using a single statement ?  Currently  querying a temporary table which is populated by iteration of INSERT statements comes to my mind.

Comment: @blabla_bingo When OP does not specify the version we may assume that actual one is used. *For versions without window functions such as 5.7 I wonder if we can do it using a single statement ?* Of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Akina.  Though it's not as pretty as the one using window function, it does get the job done in one go. Besides, using cross join to build a 4 x 4 table is really smart in this case.  Personally, I think I'll resort to a procedure with iteration for simple readability and better control. But still I thank you for your effort.

Comment: By the way, if the OP wanted to repeat 17 times, I just tested out we could built a 4 x 5 table and use a `LIMIT 51` clause to limit the output : )